# FCKeditor having issue with single quote

Tags: php

I am using fck editor in php code and facing issue while entering single quote like ' v '.
Also I am not able to use character like '\0'. If I use this it omits single quotes and also character '0'

Comment: Edit you question by removing unwanted single quotes. If you wanna highlight anything use either double quotes or use ` than single quote.

Answer (score 1):

you can `phpinfo()` and see if magic quotes are enabled - then do . If they are enabled (shame on your host) then you can make a php.ini file in the directory and put in the lines:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

and that would be fix you right up. You may need to use a .htaccess file depending on your server or webhost setup, in which case you should use the line:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply..I am using WAMP server..and in that php.ini file is already set with magic_quotes_gpc = off but it is still not working..:(

Comment: try this stripslashes() function refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_stripslashes.asp